# Sitecore 9.3 installation change webroot location

Tags: installation, sia

I have installed Sitecore 9.3 and it created the files in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`.

I would like to change some of the default settings, like

1. The webroot location to `D:` drive,
2. The SiteRootName
3. etc ...

but I'm not sure which config file to change.

Is it `setup.exe.config` or the `XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1`?

**UPDATE:**

Setup.exe.config

[image]

Comment: Qwerty, you made changes after installation or you again did fresh installation after modifying set.up.exe.config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is Sitecore only you are installing, you just need to change the setup.exe.config.

Open the setup.exe.config and add this parameter to the XPSingle template (if that is what you are installing):

```
<template name="XPSingle" path=".\XP0-SingleDeveloper.json">
  ...
  <parameter name="SitePhysicalRoot" value="[your-path]" />
</template>
```

That will make sure that Sitecore, xConnect and the IdentityServer are installed on "your path".

If you also want SXA and or Horizon to be installed in a custom root, you should read https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/11/install-sitecore-93-non-default-path.html

Answer (score 2):

The basic difference is `Setup.exe` is being used by Sitecore install assistant (GUI for easy Sitecore setup) whereas `XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1` is used by Sitecore Install Framework (Developer friendly method using PowerShell to install Sitecore).

You need to update the files according to your choice of installation method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable called `$SitePhysicalRoot` in `XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1` you can change that to change the webroot. For the Sitename change `$SitecoreSiteName`

Comment: But setup.exe.config also has that option!!!?

Comment: Use the options in setup.exe.config when running SIA